# FFmpeg, during capturing FPS changes

Tags: ffmpeg

this is what Im tried:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -acodec pcm_s16le output.mkv
```

so Im record my desktop, speed seems to be OK. But I start a game which works with 50 fps. When the game runs and being recorded, its video gets faster, as soon as I close the game, speed returns to normal. Why? It seems that I must set a forced FPS, how?